# Using Keyboard as input for XAML and C# Calculator

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I am creating a calculator using Visual Studio (C# and XAML). I want to be able to type the numbers and operation to do the calculation. without having to click on the result screen (Just like the windows default calculator). How can I achieve that? I am creating the calculator with MVVM concepts just as exercise to learn MVVM.

Answer (score 3):

You will want to use a [KeyBinding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keybinding(v=vs.110).aspx) in your XAML and bind a command to the key.

```
<Window.InputBindings>
   <KeyBinding Key="D1"
               Command="AddOneToEntryCommand" />
   <KeyBinding Key="Add"
               Command="AddCommand" />
   <KeyBinding Key="Subtract"
               Command="SubtractCommand" />
   <!-- Add bindings for all the keys and handle the logic in your commands -->
</Window.InputBindings>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use the `KeyUp` event to capture the keys the user entered.

Add it to your xaml window:

```
 KeyUp="Window_KeyUp"

private void Window_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
      string str=   e.Key.ToString();
        //do whateveer you want with that.

    }
```

Goodluck.